What is best practice when performing manual failover in a 2 node FCI
Using SQL Server 2019 with 200+ databases in a 2 node FCI, what is considered best practice regarding SQL Server Agent when performing manual failover for SQL Server CU patching. Should we manually stop the SQL Server Agent before failover?
I ask because we see that sometimes failover takes over 10 minutes, and sometimes failover takes less than 3 seconds.


Should we manually stop the SQL Server Agent before failover?

I don't see why. When a failover occurs, SQL Agent is going to be asked to shut down due to the engine shutting down and also from a request from the cluster to shutdown to move the services.

I ask because we see that sometimes failover takes over 10 minutes, and sometimes failover takes less than 3 seconds.

Do you have any data that shows it's due to SQL Agent?

No, it's random. Sometimes failover is really quick, and sometimes really slow. Just wanted to hear from the community for best practices regarding FCI failover.

You need to investigate the SQL Errorlogs and the Cluster log to understand why. @H.Engmark
